# error for push on heroku: PG::UndefinedObject: ERROR: type "string" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to push an application for Heroku and I have some errors and don't know what to do. The development mode(webrick server) works fine, send the email, etc...
I'm using a activerecord-tableless for send email contact.
this is my ContactsController:

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @contact = Contact.new
    end

    def create
        @contact = Contact.new(secure_params)
        if @contact.valid?
            UserMailer.contact_email(@contact).deliver_now
            flash[:notice] = "Message sent from #{@contact.name}."
            redirect_to root_path
        else
            flash.now[:error] = 'Cannot send message.'
            render :new
        end
    end


    private

    def secure_params
        params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email, :content)
    end

end
```

my Contact class:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base 
    has_no_table
    column :name, :string 
    column :email, :string
    column :content, :string

    validates_presence_of :name, :email, :content
    validates_format_of :email, :with => /\A[-a-z0-9_+\.]+\@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,4}\z/i
    validates_length_of :content, :maximum => 500

    def self.column(name, sql_type = nil, default = nil, null = true)
        type = "ActiveRecord::Type::#{sql_type.to_s.camelize}".constantize.new
        tableless_options[:columns] << ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column.new(name.to_s, default, type, null)
    end
end
```

view new.html.erb:

```
<% content_for :title do %>Contact<% end %>
<div class="distance">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <div align="center">
                <h2>Send a message to Us</h2>
                <%= simple_form_for @contact do |form| %>
                        <%= form.error_notification %>
                        <%= form.input :name, autofocus: true, placeholder: 'Enter name' %>
                        <%= form.input :email, placeholder: 'Enter email' %>
                        <%= form.input :content, as: :text, placeholder: 'Enter the content' %>
                        <%= form.button :submit, 'Submit', class: 'btn btn-info btn-lg' %>
                <% end %>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.2.2'
gem 'rails', '4.2.4'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
end

gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'figaro', '>= 1.0.0.rc1'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 4.4.0'
gem "activerecord-tableless", ">= 1.3.4",  git:'https://github.com/david135/activerecord-tableless.git'
group :development do
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'hub', :require=>nil
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'rails_layout'
end
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
  gem 'thin'
end
```

database.yml:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

production.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Enable Rack::Cache to put a simple HTTP cache in front of your application
  # Add `rack-cache` to your Gemfile before enabling this.
  # For large-scale production use, consider using a caching reverse proxy like
  # NGINX, varnish or squid.
  # config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Asset digests allow you to set far-future HTTP expiration dates on all assets,
  # yet still be able to expire them through the digest params.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 587,
    domain: Rails.application.secrets.domain_name,
    authentication: "plain",
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    user_name: Rails.application.secrets.email_provider_username,
    password: Rails.application.secrets.email_provider_password
  }
  # ActionMailer Config
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => Rails.application.secrets.domain_name }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8" 
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 587,
    domain: ENV["DOMAIN_NAME"], 
    authentication: "plain", 
    enable_starttls_auto: true, 
    user_name: ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"], 
    password: ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"]
  }


  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

I'm using the gem figaro and my application.yml is:

```
GMAIL_USERNAME: 'XXXXXXX'
GMAIL_PASSWORD: 'XXXXXXX'
DOMAIN_NAME: 'XXXXXXX'
OWNER_EMAIL: 'XXXXXXX@mail.com'
```

When I try to push for heroku I have this error:

```
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/motaprojectlive.git'
```

And when I try to run:

```
$  heroku run rails console
Running `rails console` attached to terminal... up, run.5541
PG::UndefinedObject: ERROR:  type "string" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT 'string'::regtype::oid
               ^
: SELECT 'string'::regtype::oid
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `async_exec': PG::UndefinedObject: ERROR:  type "string" does not exist (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
LINE 1: SELECT 'string'::regtype::oid
               ^
: SELECT 'string'::regtype::oid
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `block in execute'


$ heroku logs -t
2015-09-15T05:32:26.718951+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Thin
2015-09-15T05:32:26.718975+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.2.4 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:47284
2015-09-15T05:32:26.718977+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2015-09-15T05:32:26.718978+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2015-09-15T05:32:26.718979+00:00 app[web.1]: PG::UndefinedObject: ERROR:  type "string" does not exist
2015-09-15T05:32:26.718981+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: SELECT 'string'::regtype::oid
2015-09-15T05:32:26.718982+00:00 app[web.1]:                ^
2015-09-15T05:32:26.718983+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT 'string'::regtype::oid
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719031+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719097+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `async_exec': PG::UndefinedObject: ERROR:  type "string" does not exist (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719099+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: SELECT 'string'::regtype::oid
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719100+00:00 app[web.1]:                ^
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719110+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT 'string'::regtype::oid
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719114+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:473:in `block in log'
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719113+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `block in execute'
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719117+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:467:in `log'
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719115+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719120+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:154:in `execute'
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719121+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:393:in `lookup_cast_type'
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719122+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bundler/gems/activerecord-tableless-800393c52bd2/lib/activerecord-tableless.rb:93:in `column'
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719125+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/app/models/contact.rb:3:in `<class:Contact>'
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719126+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/app/models/contact.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719132+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719129+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719142+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:317:in `depend_on'
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719139+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:360:in `require_or_load'
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719135+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719147+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:472:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719136+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719187+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:471:in `block in eager_load!'
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719145+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:233:in `require_dependency'
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719191+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in `each'
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719192+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in `eager_load!'
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719150+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:471:in `each'
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719193+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:346:in `eager_load!'
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719196+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719197+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719195+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `each'
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719198+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719199+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719200+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719202+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719201+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719204+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719205+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719207+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719206+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719210+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719211+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719212+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719213+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719215+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719214+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719216+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719221+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719222+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719223+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719224+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719218+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719227+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719228+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719229+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719236+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:299:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719232+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719239+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in `app'
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719233+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719242+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719246+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:272:in `start'
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719243+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719248+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719251+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719255+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719254+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719258+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719263+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:8:in `require'
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719261+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2015-09-15T05:32:26.719266+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
2015-09-15T05:32:27.834264+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-09-15T05:32:27.853661+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-09-15T08:20:07.379945+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=motaprojectlive.herokuapp.com request_id=c8265c44-6398-44f4-ae08-a2077171ac55 fwd="46.27.166.60" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-09-15T08:23:47.348699+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=motaprojectlive.herokuapp.com request_id=576b4f28-174f-4b1e-8700-5053fbf3323c fwd="46.27.166.60" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-09-15T09:36:03.654458+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `rails console` by romenigld@gmail.com
2015-09-15T09:36:15.126378+00:00 heroku[run.3618]: Awaiting client
2015-09-15T09:36:15.162910+00:00 heroku[run.3618]: Starting process with command `rails console`
2015-09-15T09:36:15.516485+00:00 heroku[run.3618]: State changed from starting to up
2015-09-15T09:36:20.194081+00:00 heroku[run.3618]: State changed from up to complete
2015-09-15T09:36:20.183530+00:00 heroku[run.3618]: Process exited with status 1
2015-09-15T09:50:59.737668+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `rails console` by romenigld@gmail.com
2015-09-15T09:51:15.542149+00:00 heroku[run.1439]: Awaiting client
2015-09-15T09:51:15.750707+00:00 heroku[run.1439]: State changed from starting to up
2015-09-15T09:51:15.854508+00:00 heroku[run.1439]: Starting process with command `rails console`
2015-09-15T09:51:21.470332+00:00 heroku[run.1439]: State changed from up to complete
2015-09-15T09:51:21.462321+00:00 heroku[run.1439]: Process exited with status 1
2015-09-15T09:52:05.112988+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2015-09-15T09:52:05.113010+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation error: slug archive could not be created
2015-09-15T10:15:15.727423+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `rails console` by romenigld@gmail.com
2015-09-15T10:15:26.853219+00:00 heroku[run.5541]: Awaiting client
2015-09-15T10:15:26.885072+00:00 heroku[run.5541]: Starting process with command `rails console`
2015-09-15T10:15:27.062819+00:00 heroku[run.5541]: State changed from starting to up
2015-09-15T10:15:31.889775+00:00 heroku[run.5541]: State changed from up to complete
2015-09-15T10:15:31.877044+00:00 heroku[run.5541]: Process exited with status 1
```

Comment: This might help you with the git error "[remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)" -  https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler

Answer (score 0):

Your model is wrong.

These lines shouldn't be there.

```
column :name, :string 
column :email, :string
column :content, :string
```

Just remove them, it should work.